# How to deal with uneven spaces between bars in stacked barplot generated with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have created a stacked barplot with ggplot2. I noticed that the gaps between the bars are not the same. This is strange, as while the problem is recuring on my particular data set, I can't seem to recreate it in a reproducible manner on an exemplary frame of data.

Here is what I have done:

```
a <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C","C", "D", "E", "F", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W")
b <- c("kk", "ll", "ss", "ff", "kk", "ll", "ss", "ff", "kk", "ll", "ss", "ff", "kk", "ll", "ss", "ll", "ss", "ff", "kk", "ll", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "kk", "ll", "ss", "ff", "kk", "ss", "ss")

df <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(y = fct_infreq(a), fill = b, ), color = "black")+ 
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "\n", y = "\n")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "Subunit"))+
  ggtitle("Variation in the number of a in b \n\n")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 1))+
  expand_limits(x = c(0, 20))+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

This exemplary code returns this plot:

[image]

As you can see, everything looks fine.
This is what I get, when I run my set through the same code:

[image]

The red arrows indicate the gaps, that are noticeably thinner than other gaps.

Please advise how to correct this.

Comment: This may be a graphical artefact of the display - if you zoom into the plot onscreen or export the plot to a .png, does the issue remain?

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. Unfortunatly, the problem persists eaven if I save the plot under different extension. Zooming reveals, that gaps are indeed uneaven. Will try to render the graph on different PC.

Comment: can you provide some data to allow us to reproduce the problem?